# why we can't use the decoration and clipBehavior properties on the same Container widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget

as the title says, I want to know why we do this:

```
Container(
      clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
      child: Text("example"),
    ),
```

we get the following assertion error:

```
_AssertionError ('package:flutter/src/widgets/container.dart': Failed assertion: line 272 pos 15: 'decoration != null || clipBehavior == Clip.none': is not true.)
```

it requires that only one of them should be set.

my question why this is throws and what's the relation between both, or what it will result if they are combined in the same `Container` widget

Comment: ackward. You container follow the first assertion requirement `decoration != null`, are you sure is it the Container which triggered this exception?

Comment: Indeed, the container you showed is not the source of this issue, you can see here a snippet where a Container is being used with `decoration` and `clipBehavior` properties together (same value as yours): https://dartpad.dev/?id=05af5ab278815c7d082213bc398e4878.